# Decorated & Extended Text In a Label

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to have bold and non-bold text within a Xamarin.Forms Label widget? Is it possible to have endlines inside a Label aswell?

```
<Label Text="Abc <b>def</b>"/>
<Label Text="Abc \ndef"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to bind FormattedText style like this:

```
<Label FormattedText="{Binding CustomFormattedText}" />
```

And in model:

```
    public FormattedString CustomFormattedText
    {
        get
        {
            return new FormattedString
            {
                Spans = {
                    new Span { Text = Sum, FontAttributes=FontAttributes.Italic, FontSize="10" },
                    new Span { Text = Info, FontSize="10" } }
            };
        }
        set { }
    }
```

Comment: This actually works very good if you want to bind to a formatted text. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `FormattedString` in [the documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/fonts/#FormattedString).

You create a `FormattedString` object which consists of multiple `Span` objects, which can all have their own font, weight, color, etc.

Example:

```
var labelFormatted = new Label ();
var fs = new FormattedString ();
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { Text="Red, ", ForegroundColor = Color.Red, FontSize = 20, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic) });
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { Text=" blue, ", ForegroundColor = Color.Blue, FontSize = 32) });
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { Text=" and green!", ForegroundColor = Color.Green, FontSize = 12) });
labelFormatted.FormattedText = fs;
```

In regard to the new line, `\n` should work. Another workaround would be to do it like this:

```
<Label>
<Label.Text>
This is my magical
unicorn text
</Label.Text>
</Label>
```

Comment: The downside is that Span.Text is not bindable.

Comment: You could always create a bindable inheritance!

Comment: @pmf you can´t *Always create a bindable inheritance* since sometimes the classes sealed, which is the case of **<Span/>**

Comment: there seems to be a minor bug in the current implementation. when we do not specify a `FontSize` on each span, the font size is inherited from the `Label`, for example the `NamedSize` "Micro". But when we add a `FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold` to one span, then the font size of that one span appears about twice the size of the others on iOS 10. It can be solved by setting spans `FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, label)`